# C: strange behavior with nftw()

Tags: c, size, mode, stat

I've this code:

```
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int nftw_stat(const char *path, const struct stat *stat, int flags,
              struct FTW *ftw)
{
    if (strcmp(path, "/home/pf/.gvfs\0") == 0) {
        printf("nftw()\n");
        printf("mode = %d\n", stat->st_mode);
        printf("size = %d\n", (int) stat->st_size);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    if (nftw("/home/pf", &nftw_stat, 1, FTW_PHYS)) {
        perror("nftw");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

If I execute it normally, it returns the same way as stat() function:

```
mode = 16704 (S_IFDIR | S_IRUSR | S_IXUSR)
size = 0
```

But when I execute it with `sudo`, it returns this:

```
mode = 16832 (S_IFDIR | S_IRWXU)
size = 4096
```

What happens? If I use `stat()` with `sudo` it give me the *Permission denied* error. This happens only with `.gvfs` directory, whose permissions are 500 (dr-x------). If `sudo` can't read with `stat()` , why it works with `nftw()`? :|

Comment: What are the protections on the /home/pf directory? That controls what you see, not the permission mask on the .gvfs directory itself.

Comment: btw, you do not need to add `\\0` to C strings yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's probably happening is that stat has failed on the directory, but you are printing the values of the stat structure regardless, meaning you get rubbish.  You need to check the value of the typeflag, which you call "flags" in your nftw_stat routine to make sure that stat has successfully set the stat structure.

```
int nftw_stat(const char *path, const struct stat *stat, int typeflag,
          struct FTW *ftw)
{
  if (typeflag == FTW_NS) {
    printf("stat failed on %s\n", path);
    return 1;
  }
  if (strcmp(path, "/home/pf/.gvfs\0") == 0) {
    printf("nftw()\n");
    printf("mode = %d\n", stat->st_mode);
    printf("size = %d\n", (int) stat->st_size);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd also add `FTW_DNR` to the typeflag check

Comment: +1 for the comment, using things like stat, you should catch as much errors as possible, and read the documentation...

Comment: Thanks for FTW_DNR tip too, @Hasturkun. It will be useful. Thanks @steabert for the clear answer, I missed the typeflag argument importance.